# JSF p:outputPanel display a modal to edit the data row. in the modal, I'm unable to display the data to be edited; the fields come empty

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I created a CRUD using JSF2 and PrimeFaces, and after completing the CRUD, I decided to make some changes. In the CRUD table, there were buttons to insert, delete, and update. Previously, when I clicked to edit, I was redirected to another page with a form filled with the values of the record I wanted to modify.

However, I felt the need to, instead of being redirected to another page to perform the modification, stay on the same page and display a modal to edit the data row. However, in the modal, I'm unable to display the data to be edited; the fields come empty, as if I were inserting. Does anyone know what's happening?

```
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

     <p:dialog 
        draggable="true" 
        id="editImcs"
        widgetVar="edit"
        resizable="true" 
        showEffect="clip" 
        hideEffect="clip"
        width="360" 
        onShow="loadEvents()">

        <p:outputPanel 
            id="painelFormIcmsWrapper"  
            styleClass="row">

            <div class="col-12">
                <span class="form-group">
                    <p:outputLabel 
                        value="#{sessionMB.getLabel('label_ufsori')} " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu 
                            id="ufsoriEdit" 
                            value="#{MB.entidade.ufsori}"
                            styleClass="form-control" >
                            <f:selectItem 
                                itemLabel="" 
                                itemValue="" 
                                noSelectionOption="true"/>
                            <f:selectItems 
                                value="#{MB.ufsIcms}" 
                                var="item"
                                itemLabel="#{item.id}" 
                                itemValue="#{item.id}">
                            </f:selectItems>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>      
                </span> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <span class="form-group">
                    
                    <p:outputLabel 
                        value="#{sessionMB.getLabel('label_ufsdes')} " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu 
                            id="ufsdesEdit" 
                            value="#{MB.entidade.ufsdes}"
                            styleClass="form-control" >
                            <f:selectItem 
                                itemLabel="" 
                                itemValue="" 
                                noSelectionOption="true"/>
                            <f:selectItems 
                                value="#{MB.ufsIcms}" 
                                var="item"
                                itemLabel="#{item.id}" 
                                itemValue="#{item.id}">
                            </f:selectItems>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>          
                </span> 
            </div>

            <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                <span class="form-group">
                    <p:outputLabel for="pericmEdit" value="#{sessionMB.getLabel('label_pericm')}"/>
                    <p:inputText 
                        id="pericmEdit"
                        value="#{MB.entidade.pericm}"
                        label="#{sessionMB.getLabel('label_pericm')}" 
                        styleClass="form-control numeric" 
                        decimalPlaces="15"/>
                </span>
            </div>

        

        </p:outputPanel>

        <f:facet name="footer">

            <div class="row lineBtn">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p:commandButton 
                            type="button"
                            icon="fa fa-close" 
                            value="#{sessionMB.getLabel('label_cancelar')}"
                            styleClass="btn btn-danger d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-lowercase float-right"
                            onclick="PF('edit').hide();" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-6"> 
                    <p:commandButton 
                        icon="fa fa-save"
                        value="#{sessionMB.getLabel('label_salvar')}"
                        update="resultados  mensagensIcms"
                        partialSubmit="true"
                        process="@this ufsdesEdit ufsoriEdit pericmEdit"
                        styleClass="btn btn-primary d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-lowercase px-4"
                    />
                </div>  
            </div>

        </f:facet> 

    </p:dialog> 

    <p:growl id="mensagensIcms" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" sticky="true" />

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I figure out the answer and it is  simple, I need to use <h:form prependId="false">.

Comment: prependId=false is a bad practice. It's a leftover from JSF 1.x and discommended when using Ajax. The correct approaches are shown in abovelinked duplicates.